# How to enable Flowrouter routes in Meteor JS

Tags: meteor, flow-router

I recently went back to a meteor project and I'm trying to get my FlowRouter routes to work. At the moment its only rendering from the App.jsx file. None of my routes in lib/router.js are being used. How can I get my routes to register?

Comment: How do you import the router and the routes and how do you register the routes to the router? Can you show a simple/minimal example?

Comment: How do you register the routes?

Comment: This depends on which flow router package you actually use. Since the only current maintained one is `ostrio:flow-router-extra` you should [checkout their readme](https://github.com/veliovgroup/flow-router), which shows how to register a route.

Comment: https://github.com/kadirahq/flow-router